# Structural type in function with generic type parameter

Tags: function, scala, generics, types

While experimenting in Scala, I frequently find myself wanting to define a function for all types that define `foo`. I can do this with **Structural Typing** for simple cases, but it falls apart when a type parameter is required.

Here's a trivial example:

```
def reverse[A](xs: { def reverse(): A }): A = xs.reverse
```

This compiles without error, but fails upon passing a type that defines a `reverse` function, with the following error:

```
scala> reverse("string")
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("adsf")
 required: AnyRef{def reverse(): ?}
              reverse("adsf")
                      ^
```

I've also tried defining the structural bound on the type parameter, `[A <: { def reverse(): A }]`, but get the same sorts of results. It looks like I may be the victim of type erasure here (seeing as it expects the result of `reverse` to be `?`).

I'm not sure if this kind of type constraint is impossible in Scala's type system, or if I'm missing something. Is there some way to define a structural type for a function that has a generic parameter?

---

**Note:** I briefly considered that my problem in the given example was that `reverse` is actually defined on `StringOps`, not string. Unfortunatelly, wrapping my string in a `StringOps` container exhibits the same problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def getReverse[A](xs: {def reverse: A}): A = xs.reverse

scala> getReverse("1234")
res10: scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString = 4321
```

Apparently defining `reverse` in the structural type without parentheses works.

Comment: Apparently you can't include the empty parens. I think it interprets it as requiring `Unit` or something? It seems to be okay to use `def reverse[A](xs: {def reverse: A}): A = xs.reverse`, so naming isn't an issue. This seems like something that could've had a much better error message.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it out with my own classes. The functions `def getValue: A` and `def getValue(): A` are not both captured by a structural type of `{def getValue: A}` - only the former is. Weird.

Comment: @KChaloux ok, I'm updating the answer to mention the parentheses instead of the name scope.